# How can I script to export SVG file in both color and monochrome with Inkscape?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-interface, inkscape, monochrome

I got the following script to export my `*.svg` to `.png` in various sizes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

[[ ! -d png ]] && mkdir png/

for svg in logo.*.svg; do
  echo $svg $png
  sizes=( 64 128 256 512 1024 )
  for size in "${sizes[@]}"; do
    png="png/${svg//.svg/.$size.png}"
    [[ $png =~ vertical ]] && inkscape --without-gui --export-height=$size --export-png="$png" --file="$svg"
    [[ $png =~ horizontal ]] && inkscape --without-gui --export-width=$size --export-png="$png" --file="$svg"
  done
done
```

As I want to export both monochrome (black & white) and colour version I currently have both SVG version:

1. logo.**bw**-horizontal.svg
2. logo.**bw**-vertical.svg
3. logo.horizontal.svg
4. logo.vertical.svg

### Question

How can I improve my script to export in monochrome without the need to have a SVG file in monochrome?

#### Edit

There is a `verb`, but not sure how to use it:

```
org.inkscape.effect.filter.Silhouette: Repaint anything visible monochrome
```

Comment: did you already find a solution to this meanwhile?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Bonanza for the bump

Here are my [BATS tests](https://github.com/akema-fr/logo-groupe-trevise/blob/master/generate-logo.bats) and the related code to [do the conversion](https://github.com/akema-fr/logo-groupe-trevise/blob/master/helpers.bash). It boil down to:

1. export PNG to PNG
2. [convert PNG to monochrome](https://github.com/akema-fr/logo-groupe-trevise/blob/master/helpers.bash#L34) with `convert`

   ```
   convert "$png" -colorspace Gray "$monochrome"
   ```